# Product Of Two Cosets

Tags: group-theory

When multiplying the cosets $(1+2\mathbb{Z})(1+2\mathbb{Z})$ we multiply the element $1$ using the definition of the multiplication in its group?

So

$$(1+2\mathbb{Z})(1+2\mathbb{Z})=1+(2\mathbb{Z}2\mathbb{Z})+1=1+(2\mathbb{Z}+1)=1+(1+2\mathbb{Z})=\\=(1+1)+2\mathbb{Z}=0+2\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}?$$

Comment: $(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I$

Comment: This operation is happening in the _ring_ $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. The group operation is addition. Do the distribution carefully. You only get one $1$.

Comment: the identity of the group is 0 not 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equality
$$
(1+2\mathbb{Z})(1+2\mathbb{Z})=1+(2\mathbb{Z}2\mathbb{Z})+1
$$
is wrong. If you insist on distributing, it ought to be
$$
(1+2\mathbb{Z})(1+2\mathbb{Z})=1+2\Bbb Z + 2\Bbb Z + 2\Bbb Z\cdot 2\Bbb Z
$$
where the last three terms simplify to $2\Bbb Z$. (To be honest, I haven't checked whether distributing even makes sense here, as you're mixing together three different multiplication operations and two different addition operations with different domains. But it's probably not too hard to show if you're careful to keep the definitions straight.)

Comment: $1+2\mathbb{z}+2\mathbb{z}\cdot 2\mathbb{z}=1+2\mathbb{z}+2\mathbb{z}$ how do I continue from here?

Can it be evaluate without distribution?

Comment: the operation is addition so 1*1=2

Comment: @newhere $2\Bbb Z + 2\Bbb Z = 2\Bbb Z$, so you can simplify the last two terms. And of course it can be evaluated without distribution. You just show that any odd number is an element of $(1+2\mathbb{Z})(1+2\mathbb{Z})$ and no even number is, using the definition of multiplication of two sets of integers.